# php ffmpeg convertion to webm not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg, webm

i'm trying to convert video files to html5 formats.

it works for mp4 and ogg but not for webm.

no error shows up and also no output file

this is the code

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "upload/video.mpeg" -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 "OUTPUTFILE.mp4"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "upload/video.mpeg" -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 "OUTPUTFILE.webm"');
exec('ffmpeg -i "upload/video.mpeg" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis trailer.webm');
exec('ffmpeg -i "upload/video.mpeg" -b 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -g 30 "OUTPUTFILE.ogv"');
```

Comment: You are not capturing the output. The error message is probably there. see the second argument in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Not much we can do without the console outputs/logs. `-vpre slow -vpre baseline` should be `-preset slow -profile:v baseline`. `-b` should be `-b:v`. ogv is a waste of time since you're including webm.

Comment: ok there was some misconfiguration